# extending parent django template, as well as including a variable

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a base template that I'm trying to extend.  With in that template I have a navigation that needs a variable passed.

What I was doing was trying to 'extend' it by using an include like so:

```
{% include "base.html" with active_nav='atInventory' %}
```

but this doesn't render the blocks of the base with the extended content in the right order.

The navigation is set up in the base like so:

```
    <nav class="col-xs-12 paddingVertical-sm">
        <ul class="removePadding removeMargin txtXxs">
            <li class="{% if active_nav == 'atContact' %} activeNav {% else %} inactiveNav{% endif %}">
                <a href="{% url 'contact' %}">CONTACT<a>
            </li>
            <li class="{% if active_nav == 'atAbout' %} activeNav {% else %} inactiveNav{% endif %}">
                <a href="{% url 'about' %}">ABOUT</a>
            </li>
            <li class="{% if active_nav == 'atProjects' %} activeNav {% else %} inactiveNav{% endif %}">
                <a href="{% url 'projects' %}">PROJECTS & CLINICS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="{% if active_nav == 'atServices' %} activeNav {% else %} inactiveNav{% endif %}">
                <a href="{% url 'services' %}">SERVICS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="{% if active_nav == 'atInventory' %}  activeNav {% else %} inactiveNav{% endif %}">
                <a href="{% url 'inventory' %}">INVENTORY</a>
            </li>
            <li class="{% if active_nav == 'atHome' %} activeNav {% else %} inactiveNav{% endif %}">
                <a href="{% url 'index' %}">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <br class="clear-fix">
        </ul>
        <img src="{% static 'images/assets/klossviolins_logo.png' %}" />
        <br class="clear-fix">
    </nav>
```

Is there a better way to do this?  Or does this just require a slight tweak?  Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: Are you trying to include template or extend it? What is the main template?

Comment: don't try to extend with an include...it breaks the principles of logics... why not simply extending it? or make a block for that special area that uses `active_nav`

Comment: yea, I was thinking about using a block and then using an include with in that block?  I'm trying to extend the template, it basically is just the top navigation and footer.

Answer (score 0):

nI wouldn't do this - extend it the way it was intended. Include is for including reusable components. Here you just want every template to extend your 'base.html' with {%extends 'base.html'%}

Just a pointer as well - I'd do the active nav with a tiny script instead of tons of if statements. So add an ID to each li element (#nav-home for index in my example), and on your home page have something like:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $( "#nav-home").addClass("activeNav");
 });
</script>
```